# docker-compose does not accept my volumes declaration

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use docker-compose. I started off by copying an example from the docker documentation:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"

networks:
  webnet:

volumes:
  - type: volume
    source: mydata
    target: /data
    volume:
      nocopy: true
  - type: bind
    source: ./static
    target: /opt/app/static
```

but what I get is: `ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', volume must be a mapping, not an array.`

It looks to me something to do with an old version of docker-compose. So I tried to update my docker running on MacOs, but it's up to date. By checking the version this is what I get:

```
Matteos-MacBook-Pro-2:chateo matteo$ docker-compose -v   
docker-compose version 1.14.0, build c7bdf9e
```

shouldn't it be 1.17? I don't get it. Any hints?

### Update

I've tried to replace the array with a key:value list:

```
volumes:
  mydata:
    type: volume
    source: mydata
    target: /data
    volume:
      nocopy: true
  static:
    type: bind
    source: ./static
    target: /opt/app/static
```

But what I get is the following:

```
Matteos-MacBook-Pro-2:chateo matteo$ docker-compose build
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
volumes.static value Additional properties are not allowed ('source', 'type', 'target' were unexpected)
volumes.mydata value Additional properties are not allowed ('volume', 'source', 'type', 'target' were unexpected)
```

Comment: I got this error when the identation of the `volumes:` was wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Using this syntax, the volume definition should be inside the service using it, see [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes)

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: mydata
        target: /data
        volume:
          nocopy: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./static
        target: /opt/app/static

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/postgres/postgres.sock:/var/run/postgres/postgres.sock"
      - "dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"

volumes:
  mydata:
  dbdata:
```

Otherwise, you can declare a volume with specific driver [like this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference):

```
version: "3.2"
volumes:
  mydata:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: uid=500,gid=500
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `volumes` definition to something like this:

```
volumes:
  mydata:
    type: volume
    source: mydata
    target: /data
    volume:
      nocopy: true
  static:
    type: bind
    source: ./static
    target: /opt/app/static
```

I can be wrong, but volumes cant be array.

Comment: Nope, I've already tried it. I'll update the question with this

Comment: propably you need to update docker-compose. Your docker-compose does not support 'volume', 'source', 'type', 'target' attributes

Comment: I totally agree. But according to the docs, MacOs' docker-compose version is updated along with docker. And docker is up to date! #scratchingHead